# How to count dynamically added table rows with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

How can I count the table rows that is added dynamically with jQuery?

I have tried with `$('#mytbody').children().length;` but it doesn't work with rows that are added dynamically.

Here is my code, also [runnable in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8sBr/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#add').bind('click', function() {
        $('#mytbody').after('<tr><td>'+ new Date() +'</td></tr>');
        var count = $('#mytbody').children().length;
        $('#counter').html(count);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="add">Add row</button>
<table>
    <tbody id="mytbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
Number of rows: <span id="counter"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding rows outside of tbody.

Change `after` to `prepend`

will work..

or change count to `var count = $('table tr').length;`

http://jsfiddle.net/H8sBr/442/

Comment: Thanks, changing `after` to `prepend` fixed my problem.

Comment: This jsfiddle doesn't work. The number of rows is always shown as zero. I don't understand how was it chosen as answer! Solution by @meo works great.

Comment: Hi @sankar.suda....Jsfiddle doesn`t work.Let me know how to get this ?How to solve this....

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/H8sBr/2/

you need to use `.append()` not `.after()`. After adds a element After your tbody but you count elements Inside your tbody. If you use append, you add them at the end of the tbody. Alternately you could use `.prepend()` to add entries on top of the table.

PS: This is a commun misconception because of the css selector `.after()` that adds content after the content of the selected element not after the element.

Comment: Hi @meo....thank a lot its working perfectly....I get solution for this with your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try altering count to

```
var count = $('table tr').length;
```

This seems to work - not sure why acting on the tbody doesn't.

Edit: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whostolemyhat/H8sBr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[Just use a counter,it has less dom lookups](http://jsfiddle.net/FcXdA/2/)  :

```
$(function() {
    $('#counter').html(0);
    var count = 1;
    $('#add').bind('click', function() {
        $('#mytbody').after('<tr><td>'+ new Date() +'</td></tr>');
        $('#counter').html(count);
        count++
    });
});
```

Comment: this would be perfect if you set the counter to the length of the tr that are already there... Maybe there could be some

Comment: This also works, but I prefer to not introduce another variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is some bug (not sure) in jQuery; row length is not getting updated if you add table row dynamically.

```
var rowCount = $("#tableId > tbody > tr").length;
```

will not return correct count if you add row dynamically.

Simple solution is to use:

```
var rowCount = document.getElementById("tableId").rows.length;
```

Yes, you can use jQuery with javascript.